# Change color for text when text field Disabled using onClick?

Tags: javascript, html

Here I am trying to do is when we click button the text filed default value color should be changed. My code is applying for all browsers except IE. How to overcome this problem in IE. How to do it for dropdown list.

```
<html>
<head>
 <title> Change color for text when it is Disabled </title>
 <meta name="Generator" content="EditPlus">
         <script type="text/javascript">
      <!--
/*function changeColor(){
    document.getElementById('button_1').style.color='red';
}*/
function changeColor(){
    document.getElementById('color').removeAttribute('disabled');
    document.getElementById('color').style.color='red';
    document.getElementById('color').setAttribute('readOnly','readOnly');
}
      //-->
  </script>
   </head>

  <body>
      <input type="text"  value='Hi Conrep' disabled id='color'><br />
        <select id='color' disabled>
<option value='1'>1</option>
<option value='2'>2</option>
<option value='3'>3</option>
<option value='4'>4</option>
<option value='5'>5</option>
<option value='6'>6</option>
   </select><br />
     <select>
     <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
        <option value="saab">Saab</option>
      <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
        <option value="audi">Audi</option>
   </select> 
   <input type='button' value="Change Color" onclick ='changeColor();'>
  </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

For cross-browser you need to use `readonly` attributes instead of disabled.

**Example**

```
<style type="text/css">
.redColor
{
    color:red;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
function changeColor()
{
    var el = document.getElementById('button_1');
    el.className = "redColor";
}
//-->
</script>
<input type="text"  value='Hi Conrep' readonly id='button_1'>
<input type='button' value="Change Color" onClick ='changeColor();'>
```

Comment: @SachinMalmanchi if you use the disabled attribute, no matter what you try IE will refuse all of them...i read it somewhere..and its true..

Comment: @SachinMalmanchi same..define id and add class...but again IE will not allow to add css for drop down...you need plugins that do that..

Answer (score 0):

that's because, IE doesn't let you modify `disabled` control. it will always render them that way

in your code try this:

```
<style>
  .IEFormat
  {
      color:Red;
      background-color:#CCCCCC;
      border:1px Solid #BBBBBB;
  }
  .Format
  {
      color:Red;
  }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
  navigator.sayswho= (function(){
    var N= navigator.appName, ua= navigator.userAgent, tem;
    var M= ua.match(/(opera|chrome|safari|firefox|msie)\/?\s*(\.?\d+(\.\d+)*)/i);
           if(M && (tem= ua.match(/version\/([\.\d]+)/i))!= null) M[2]= tem[1];
             M= M? [M[1], M[2]]: [N, navigator.appVersion,'-?'];
          return M;
  })();
  function changeColor(){    
      var elem = document.getElementById('button_1');
      if(navigator.sayswho.toString().indexOf("IE")>0)
      {
         if(elem.getAttribute('disabled'))
            elem.removeAttribute('disabled');
         elem.className="IEFormat";
         elem.setAttribute('readOnly','readOnly');
      }     
      else
         elem.className='Format';
}
</script>
```

so basically what you are doing is, you are detecting the browser, run your current for all the other browsers and a different one for IE.

You can make your readonly textbox looklike disabled in IE through style. :)